# How to create ADO.NET Entity Framework ObjectContext extensions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'd like to create the context extension methods described in [Cesar de la Torre's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/cesardelatorre/archive/2008/09/04/updating-data-using-entity-framework-in-n-tier-and-n-layer-applications-short-lived-ef-contexts.aspx).

But I'm not sure how to declare the class that holds my extension methods.

[Griff Townsend](http://grifftownsend.blogspot.com/2008/08/small-extension-to-entity-framework.html) wrote:

> If I include a reference to this class
>   (or have the class in my namespace),
>   any ObjectContext references will be
>   able to execute these extensions:
>
> [image: ADO.NET Entity Framework extension method intellisense]
>
> If you look at the tool tip in the
>   photo above, you should be able to see
>   that I can now cleanly access any
>   function that I add to the EntitySet
>   that I create.

How do I declare the class that holds my extension methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to declare a static class :

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    // extension methods go here
}
```

Comment: Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922402/strongly-typed-asp-net-mvc-with-ado-net-entity-framework